# Laravel Homestead can't connect to db

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-4

I'm having trouble connecting to the database when using Laravel Homestead. I can't really understand why it doesn't work I've tried god damn everything I guess. Now i got stuck and can't try much more and I start to interact with more people. Does stackoverflow have any good answer or advice to give me? :)

This is my settings

```
'mysql' => array(
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => $_ENV['DB_HOST'],
    'database'  => $_ENV['DB_NAME'],
    'username'  => $_ENV['DB_USERNAME'],
    'password'  => $_ENV['DB_PASSWORD'],
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
    'port'      => '33060'
)
```

I've also tried this with the same response.

```
'mysql' => array(
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => $_ENV['DB_HOST'],
    'database'  => $_ENV['DB_NAME'],
    'username'  => $_ENV['DB_USERNAME'],
    'password'  => $_ENV['DB_PASSWORD'],
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
    'port'      => '3306'
)
```

This is my ENV variables.

```
{
host: "127.0.0.1",
database: "homestead",
username: "homestead",
password: "secret"
}
```

The return is:

```
PDOException
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)
```

In both Migrations as the website.

It works to connect with Sequel Pro, it looks like this in Sequel Pro.
[image]

**EDIT:Is it possible that there's some kinda collision between my VagrantBox's IP and the MAMP one? I've stopped every MAMP thing I've running but still the same issue, just wondering if I need to stop it somewhere else?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't need to specify the port at all, I'd remove that line. For host, try `localhost` instead. Also make sure that Homestead uses the environment you have set your database to, most likely `local`.

MAMP can't conflict with it, unless you've at some point manually set your MAMP MySQL port to 33060, which I very much doubt.

Here's a default file which works great for me:

```
'mysql' => array(
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'database'  => 'mydbname',
    'username'  => 'homestead',
    'password'  => 'secret',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
),
```

Lycka till!

Comment: Thanks alot! The problem were the "host", I also made vagrant destroy && vagrant up and then it worked. It might have been a combination of them both! Thanks alot for your help!. I also removed the port.

Answer (score 0):

What have you got when you open the PHP REPL by typing `php artisan tinker` at the root of your project and then `print_r(Config::get('database.connections')['mysql']);` ?

You should have this:

```
Array
(
    [driver] => mysql
    [host] => localhost
    [database] => homestead
    [username] => homestead
    [password] => secret
    [charset] => utf8
    [collation] => utf8_unicode_ci
    [prefix] => 
    [port] => 33060
)
```

If you have something different your environment variables are not good or you are not detecting the local environment.